# How to make grid faster in python

Tags: python

I have 3 arrays of the same dimension `alt = np.array(186 values)`, `sza = np.array(186 values)` and `per = np.array(186 values)`. I need to make a grid with the `per` values over `(alt,sza)`.

I have tried the following code and it is time-consuming process. Can anyone suggest improvisation for the code.

```
als = np.arange(150,510,5)
szde = np.arange(90,190,5)

val2 = []                
for h in range(len(als)-1):
    val1=[]
    for h1 in range(len(szde)-1):
        val=[]
        for h2 in range(len(per)):
            if ((als[h+1] >= alt[h2] >= als[h]) and (szde[h1+1] >= sza[h2] >= szde[h1])):  
                val.append(np.array(per[h2]).ravel())
        val1.append(np.array(np.mean(val)))        
    val2.append(val1)      
      
# val2 is gridded data
```

Let me know if any clarification is needed.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you give us a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Hello, You can take some random 186 alt values going between (150 to 500) and similarly sza values of (90 to 180). per is in my case percentage of pressure values (20,25,33,45,96,100,85,65,..so on total of 186 values). This values I have grid over alt and sza values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to found an alternative method, which worked faster for me.
I am posting as the result.

```
als = np.arange(150,510,5)
szde = np.arange(90,190,5)

res=[]
for h in range(len(als)-1):
    tempu=[]
    for h2 in range(len(szde)-1):            
        a11=np.logical_and((alt<als[h+1]),(alt>als[h]))
        a22=np.logical_and((sza<szde[h2+1]),(sza>szde[h2]))
        tempu.append(np.nanmean(per[np.where(np.logical_and(a11,a22)==True)]))
    res.append(tempu)
res=np.array(res)
```

res is the gridded array of (72,19)